# How to combine/reduce multiple rows from a dataframe that share the same ID based on a business rule?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
   A  B  C.  ID  
0. 1. 0. 1.   1
1. 0. 0. 1.   2 
2. 1. 1  0.   1 
3. 0  1. 0.   3
.....
```

I want to reduce the dataframe so that only unique ID's remain. The business rule I want to apply is that if user `n` has multiple rows then they should be merged and the value `1` should take precedent over `0`. So in the example dataframe, user with ID `1` has two rows (0 and 2). These should be reduced to

```
A B C
1 1 1
```

What would be the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: Have a look at the `groupby()` command in combination with `max()` that should return 1.

Answer (score 1):

```
pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'A': {0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 0},
        'B': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 1},
        'C': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 0, 3: 0},
        'ID': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 3}
    }
).groupby('ID').max()
```

Output:

```
    A  B  C
ID         
1   1  1  1
2   0  0  1
3   0  1  0
```